# Pandas: How to find out if data from one table falls within the range of a second table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a time of two orders made in one day:
[Time of two payments in one day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7RJM.jpg)

And the time when all the applications were used
[Time of using all applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyaLQ.jpg)

Question: given a time from first table when then order was made, how can we identify the time period in the second table?

Comment: Don't post dataframes and code as images.  post them in your question as text.

Comment: Okay, next time will post without images. Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score -1):

You can identify for each order which applications where used at that time. Obviously, there might be more that one applications running at that time. Say that your orders are store in a dataframe called `order_df` and the application info in another called `application_df`. Then you can loop over all orders and check which applications where running (storing the results in a dict):

```
order_map = {}
for ix, it in order_df.iterrows():
    order_id = it['OrderId']
    order_time = it['Time']
    condition = (application_df['StartTime'] <= order_time) & (application_df['EndTime'] >= order_time)
    order_map[order_id] = application_df[condition]['ApplicationID'].values
```